# Neo4jClient Return NodeReference from cypher query

Tags: cypher, neo4jclient, nodereference

I have a query:

```
 var results = new CypherFluentQuery(_client)
       .Start("n", (NodeReference)0)
       .Match(string.Format("(n)-[:{0}]--(x)", UserBelongsTo.TypeKey))
       .Return<User>("x")
       .Results;
```

This returns me all of the nodes that match the query of type User. How would I perform the same query but return the NodeReferences for each of those matched Users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
.Return<Node<User>>("x")
```

and it will return the `Node` which has a `Reference` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.Return(n => n.Id)
```

This feature exists only from latest versions of neo4jclient (06/2013)